# Apply numbering 1-n for every variable in a long form data frame containing NaN values

Tags: r

Say I have a long form data frame, of time series data, basically. It's going to look like this. Somewhere along my conversion of raw data the numbering got lost, and so I'd like to get back a column of frame numberings (starting from 1).

The `$frame` column is my desired output.

Edit: Newly added `NaN` values in my example, see comments below. Also changed title of question to reflect this specifically.

```
name value frame
A     41     1
A     NaN    2
A     72     3   
B     24     1
B     51     2    
C     28     1
C     NaN    2
C     57     3
C     NaN    4
C     34     5   
D     24     1
D     75     2
```

Comment: `ave(seq_along(df$value), df$value, FUN = seq_along)`

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Thanks, `seq_along` is very simple and useful. After testing it out I'll add that it's a better idea to use `df$name`, as NA values screw up the numbering.

Comment: Ah, sorry for mixing them up. I added some random numbers to go along with `NaN` for numerical data.